# R Barplot: Y-axis cut off at the top?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to use R to do a barplot.  Values I'm plotting range from 0 to 5.0, but are decimal values (such as 4.87) so I don't want to just use the default Y axis, because it just goes up in increments of 1.

I've created a custom Y axis, which works, but if I set the maximum value greater than about 4.5, it cuts off the tickmark at the top of the axis.  This looks untidy so I want a way to ensure this tickmark will always appear, but I don't want to shorten my axis as it looks stupid if I do this.

My R code is as follows:

```
# Bar plot of mean SUS question scores
barplot(meanSUSQuestions$Mean,
        main="Mean SUS Question Scores",
        cex.main="0.8",
        cex.axis="0.8",
        cex.lab="0.8",
        #names=c("q1", "q2", "q3","q4","q5","q6","q7","q8","q9","q10"),
        names=c(1:10),
        yaxt="n",
        col="red")
axis(2, cex.axis="0.8", at=seq(0, 5, 0.5)) # Create custom Y axis
mtext(text="Mean Score", side=2, line=2, cex=0.8)
mtext(text="Question", side=1, line=2, cex=0.8)
```

The bar plot that this produces looks like this:

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the top tickmark is missing.

How can I get this top tickmark to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`barplot` generates the image height based on the data. The range of your manual y-axis is considerably larger than the plot area and is thus cut off.

The easiest way to solve the issue in your specific case is to add an `yaxp = c(0, 5, 11)` to `barplot` instead of `yaxt = "n"` and `axis`.

A self-contained example:

```
# Bad
x <- 1:5
barplot(x, yaxt = "n") #, add = TRUE)
axis(2, at = seq(0, 6, 2)) # Create custom Y axis

# Good
barplot(x, yaxp = c(0, 6, 2))
```

Comment: This worked when I used the following:

yaxp = c(0, 5, 20),